# Python vs. compiled languages in OR research using metaheuristics

Tags: python, metaheuristics, c++, academia, journals

In many articles that use metaheuristics to solve optimization problems, the programming language of choice is C++. For example, the following two articles present state-of-the-art metaheuristics to solve the Capacitated Vehicle Routing Problem and are implemented in C++: [Accorsi and Vigo (2021)](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/trsc.2021.1059?casa_token=qfY8kgSxjT4AAAAA:Jq8ud5gC60Jz0QKbszOv3fGpBhMuuT8wAHY47Fe09-kHXn0OZoFotiP7rlE5oQ-mRJm6X_BT_zLp) and [Vidal (2022)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S030505482100349X?via%3Dihub).

I have yet to find a paper that uses Python to implement a metaheuristic for routing or scheduling problems. As I recently started my PhD in this field and I only have experience with programming in Python, I'm wondering whether it's even acceptable to use Python for my research.

Assuming that the algorithmic aspects of my code are efficient (e.g., implementing local search methods in the best-known time complexity, using efficient data structures), would it hurt my chances to publish in top quality journals if I use Python in my research instead of C++ or another compiled language?

Although I have not read a lot of literature on exact methods, I believe this issue is less prevalent because most people make use of commercial solvers such as CPLEX and Gurobi. But if my question also applies in this case, please feel free to share your thoughts on this as well.

Comment: What is the scientific contribution of your work? Do you want to beat a benchmark of an existing problem or do you come up with a new problem?

Comment: @PeterD The main scientific contribution of my work is solving real-world optimization problems. For example, solving a rich vehicle routing problem with 5+ attributes or scheduling problems such as hybrid flexible flow shop with again lots of constraints.

Comment: I would recommend you to learn C++ now. Otherwise, you're just going to make your research harder until you accept to learn it - and you will anyway if you stay in the field of heuristics. A good Python implementation will be 10 times slower than a good C++ implementation and won't even be that easy to implement

Comment: You could also learn [**C**ython](https://cython.org/) if performance is your main concern.

Comment: I see a performance cost to using Pyhon. For example [OptaPy](https://www.optapy.org) on the [Vehicle Routing Problem](https://github.com/optapy/optapy-quickstarts/blob/stable/vehicle-routing/README.adoc) is significantly slower than in Java with OptaPlanner (although that gap is shrinking). **But in practice, ease of development** (such as using a language in which you are proficient, with strong library ecosystem, etc) **is far more important than picking the right programming language.**

Comment: @joni Cython is relevant if you work on a Python project and you need to optimize a specific part of the program. But not if you're choosing the tools you're going to use in the next 10 years. It would be much more complex to use in the end and won't even reach the performances of pure C++

Comment: @fontanf I like both Cython and C++. However, Cython can be used as a standalone language, so it's more than just a tool to optimize specific parts of your python code. And IMO, Cython is much easier to learn than C++ when coming from Python. *Good* Cython code can easily match the performance of pure C++ (which requires a good knowledge of both languages, to be fair).

Comment: It's worth noting that Python (in the default implementation) [is actually compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6889798/4782863). So I don't think "Python vs. compiled languages" is the correct question to ask. Why do you even care if it's compiled? If the answer is "performance", then I recommend you ask about performance specifically.

Comment: You should seriously consider [Julia](https://www.quora.com/How-do-C-Cython-and-Julia-compare-in-terms-of-execution-time?top_ans=200567055). If you know Python, Julia you'll find close enough (for starters). And if you need C-grade efficiency, default Julia comes close. And, in the hands of experts, often betters C.

Comment: An eg why Julia in OR makes sense https://juliacomputing.com/case-studies/alpha-route/

Comment: @joni Cython code is just somewhat parsed Python. Instead of converting to C data, all variables are directly used as their Cpython internal representation (`Gill` and reference counting).

Comment: @marcelm it is compiled into an intermediate representation which is then interpreted. Also function names aren’t compiled, it is only at run time it is known if a variable/object/function was declared or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Speaking as an occasional reviewer for journals, when I read a paper proposing a new heuristic or metaheuristic my first question is "does it work?", which is independent of the programming language used. My second question is "does it work better than existing methods?", which can be interpreted in one of two ways: it gets better results than currently accepted methods in the same amount of time; or it gets comparable results faster. Depending on the underlying type of problem being solved, "accepted methods" might include running a commercial optimization solver in a heuristic way (set a time limit, tweak a few settings and see how good the incumbent solution is).

So this ties into the question @PeterD put in his comment. If this is a new, previously unsolved, problem and it does not fit into a category (LP, MILP, ...) for which solvers exist, just producing "reasonable" results in "reasonable" time is grounds for publication. If there are no commonly used heuristics for the problem, getting a solution that is fairly good in a reasonable time may be enough for publication, even if commercial solvers do better, because not everyone can afford commercial solvers. If, say, the problem is frequently solved (by practitioners and/or in the research literature) using the horny snail metaheuristic, than I would expect you as author to demonstrate that your metaheuristic is faster than horny snail, either by running both of them on the same examples using the same hardware or by citing published times for horny snail on publicly available test problems and then beating those times with your heuristic (on hardware comparable to what was used for the published times).

Now, can you accomplish any of that in Python. Quite possibly. The published times for other heuristics might have been generated using Python code, or code in languages "slower" than C/C++. There is also the question of coding skill: your "tight" Python code might run faster than someone else's sloppy C++ code. Also, libraries play a role. The bulk of the computing time spent by your heuristic might occur in a Python library, written in C/C++ by someone who worked to optimize their code.

If nothing else, you could start by coding in Python and see if your heuristic works (valid results, reasonably close to optimal in reasonable time and memory). If you think it has merit but is not yet publishable, maybe you could bring on a coauthor with C/C++ programming chops (or hire someone to recode it).

Comment: A well written C++17 program has very different and often more readable architecture that is not easily reproducible in Python. As a result, "Python first" may not be the best approach for a complex algorithm.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a false dichotomy.

Surely, C++ is the classical language for fast programs (besides FORTRAN, maybe).

But nowadays, Java is very fast as well. Julia is also an option, fast and aimed for scientific programming.

So you do not necessarily go down into the depth of memory management in C++, there are alternatives.

Comment: I agree with you and to be fair, discussions on languages are always a bit biased. But I still couldn't resist mentioning that *memory management in C++* isn't this much of an issue in modern C++ thanks to RAII, smart pointers and the STL containers.

Comment: @joni This is a fair point. C++ has become much simpler in this respect.

Answer (score 3):

Python has something named the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) which prevents any kind of shared memory parallelism and even sometimes message based parallelism. In theory, it is possible to serialize objects if they are small but [most Python bindings don’t and won’t implement what is required for bringing parallelism capacity](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/4935).
As a result, many Python programs with huge amount of work to bring serialization support across all dependencies/subdependencies **are finding themselves having to rely on single-thread CPU performance with running during weeks on a specific problem still in 2022**!

And unlike languages like Java, Python uses reference counting instead of garbage collection in a separate thread which adds work in an already single-thread-bound language.

On the other hand, languages like C++ or Fortran don’t suffer from the warm up time of JIT languages like Java or JavaScript nor the slow execution speed of language like Python or/along the Cythonized version.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that removing the GIL is an active discussion once again. There are proof-of-concept forks of Python which implement this already.

Comment: @tripleee many proofs of concepts during all over the last decade but nothing which can be used with existing software besides Jython which is still Python 2. Even the new Microsoft implementation starting this year took the design choice to say it’s up to each Python module to implement proper serialization for allowing parallelism which of course won’t happen. *A proper way to do this would be to simply require C extensions along generated Cython code to no longer assume thread‐safety which obviously would be more difficult than Python 2 to Python 3*.

Comment: **More seriously, if you need at least message‐based parallelism without having to reinvent the wheel by writing your own flavour of most Python packages,** just use C/C++/Fortran but don’t expect anything before 2040 with Python…

Answer (score 1):

The most convincible way to compare the performance of the different algorithms is by implementing them in the same language and profiling on the same hardware. If one runs Python on mainframe and another C++ on your toaster, the results are largely unpredictable.

Obviously you can also use other ways to convince like proving the O(n) complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: How is this perceived by reviewers when I implement an algorithm in Python that was originally published/implemented using C/C++? For example, let's say the current state-of-the-art is algorithm A and I propose a new algorithm B. Even if I would re-implement A in Python and compare it against my metaheuristic B - both sharing many data structures and local search operators - then my Python implemention of A is still at a disadvantage vs. the C/C++ implemented A. @prubin what are your thoughts on this given your previous answer?

Comment: A good reviewer won't accept this. It's too easy to do a bad implementation. If you re-implement the algorithm you're comparing with, you need to get equivalent performances as the original version